# pandas combine two dfs: leave none if either df has null value at that index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, group-by

I want to combine two data frames in such a way that if for one of the df, the value is null at an index, it should retain null value. For example, in the code below for df_combine at index 0 for column yyy, it should retain np.nan.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'xxx':['ind',np.nan,'ind'],'yyy':[np.nan,'pin','din']}, orient='columns')
    >>df1
       xxx  yyy
    0  ind  NaN
    1  NaN  pin
    2  ind  din

df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'xxx':['0.12','0.15','0.18','8.1'],'yyy':['9.2','1.1',np.nan,'7.1']}, orient='columns')
    >>df2
        xxx  yyy
    0  0.12  9.2
    1  0.15  1.1
    2  0.18  NaN
    3   8.1  7.1
```

Desired output:

```
 >>df_combine
             xxx       yyy
    0    ind||0.12   np.nan
    1     np.nan     pin||1.1
    2    ind||0.18     din
```

Comment: Please see my edits. I added my desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do this:

```
In [92]: df1.add('||').add(df2.values)
Out[92]:
         xxx       yyy
0  ind||0.12       NaN
1        NaN  pin||1.1
2  ind||0.18       NaN
```

Setup:

```
In [86]: df1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'xxx':['ind',np.nan,'ind'],'yyy':[np.nan,'pin','din']}, orient='columns')

In [87]: df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'xxx':['0.12','0.15','0.18'],'yyy':['9.2','1.1',np.nan]}, orient='columns')

In [88]: df1
Out[88]:
   xxx  yyy
0  ind  NaN
1  NaN  pin
2  ind  din

In [89]: df2
Out[89]:
    xxx  yyy
0  0.12  9.2
1  0.15  1.1
2  0.18  NaN
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [126]: df1.add('||').add(df2.iloc[:len(df1)].values)
Out[126]:
         xxx       yyy
0  ind||0.12       NaN
1        NaN  pin||1.1
2  ind||0.18       NaN
```

Comment: Wonderful solution. I did not know about the add. I could have accepted this answer if only this was working on two dfs with different dimensions which is the case with my real data. Suppose I add one more row to the df2, it will not work. I have made edits to the my original question.

Comment: @Rtut, what about your desired data set? is it still the same?

Comment: If useful to someone. For my actual data, I did something like this to include search based on indexes. I am still testing how well this works.                                    df2_subset= df2.loc[df1.index]                                                                                ,    df1.add('||').add(df2_subset.values)